# Jenkins SCM poll with release build

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build which will run some maven targets upon an SCM change. These basically ensure all the tests pass.

I would like to have a button **on the same Jenkins job** that will run the same build plus an additional maven targets which deploy into nexus.

Is this possible?

Comment: can this be achieved via a parameterized job which defaults to run test cases which can be run via SCM polling and whenever you want to publish it to Nexus, you can use the second parameter to do it.

Comment: Let me know if this is not what you are looking for in which case you can provide more information of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Nexus artifact Uploader](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader)

or

you can use curl in the "execute shell" with job parameter :

```
curl -v -u admin:admin --upload-file pom.xml http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/artifact/1.0/artifact-1.0.pom
```